# Swagger как настроить отображение spring data rest вручную?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, swagger

есть сервис на spring boot, в нем используется spring data rest. В помнике подключаю стартер.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

для того, чтобы не отображало кучу служебных контроллеров которые создаются автоматом в конфиге пишу название

```
 .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.mypackage"))
```

В итоге data rest контроллеры ессно не отображаются. Можно их как то добавить вручную?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так, если у вас необходимые контроллеры являются RestController

```
 .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
```